# Displaying multiple routes to the same destination on the map google, is it possible?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make multiple routes to the same destination, so I was trying to loop this function, with different value for params *startLatLong

```
function initialize() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.174465,106.822745),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    displayRoute(map.getCenter());
    displayRoute({lat:-6.225014,lng:106.900447})

}

function displayRoute(startLatLong) {
            var start = startLatLong;
            var end = '-6.2451528, 106.7923695'; 
            var request = {
              origin:start, 
              destination:end,
              travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    var myRoute = response.routes[0];
                    var txtDir = '';
                    for (var i=0; i<myRoute.legs[0].steps.length; i++) {
                        txtDir += myRoute.legs[0].steps[i].instructions+"<br />";
                    }
                    document.getElementById('directions').innerHTML = txtDir;
                }
            });
    }
```

but, the result just showing the last of loop value.

Can anyone explain, is it possible, to create multiple routes in a same destination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display multiple directions at the same time, you need a separate `DirectionsRenderer` object for each:

```
function displayRoute(startLatLong) {
  var start = startLatLong;
  var end = '-6.2451528, 106.7923695'; 
  var request = {
    origin:start, 
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  $scope.directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
       var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map:map, preserveViewport: true});
       directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
     } else alert("directions request failed: status:"+status)
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr4n2aLo/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var $scope = {};

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.174465, 106.822745),
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  $scope.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  displayRoute(map.getCenter());
  displayRoute({
    lat: -6.225014,
    lng: 106.900447
  });
  displayRoute({
    lat: -6.202394,
    lng: 106.65271
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function displayRoute(startLatLong) {
  var start = startLatLong;
  var end = '-6.2451528, 106.7923695';
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  $scope.directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map,
        preserveViewport: true
      });
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else alert("directions request failed: status:" + status)
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```